REplit + Node JS - How to override local file JSON data
My code snippet works with node js but my actual file “LOCAL_JSON_FILE_PATH” does not update with the new data. I want to remove old data from the file and import new data at set times.
My code works because I see the console logs but my file “LOCAL_JSON_FILE_PATH” does not actually gain any data. What is wrong?
Console logs:
07-05 09:50:04
Local JSON file updated successfully at FILELOCATION.json
07-05 09:50:04
Updated file content: {


async function stepOne() {
  try {
    console.log('Fetching Knack record...');
    const response = await fetch(API_URL_stepOne, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-Knack-Application-ID': APP_ID,
        'X-Knack-REST-API-Key': API_KEY,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });


    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorText = await response.text();
      console.error('Error response text:', errorText);
      throw new Error(`Error fetching record: ${response.statusText} - ${errorText}`);
    }

    const data = await response.json();

    return data.records[0]; 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch Knack record:', error);
    throw new Error(`Failed to fetch Knack record: ${error.message}`);
  }
}


async function stepTwo(url) {
  try {
    console.log('Downloading JSON data from URL:', url);
    const response = await fetch(url);

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to download JSON data: ${response.statusText}`);
    }

    const jsonData = await response.json();
    console.log('Downloaded JSON data:', JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2));

    fs.writeFile(LOCAL_JSON_FILE_PATH, JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2), 'utf8', (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Failed to update local JSON file:', err);
      } else {
        console.log(`Local JSON file updated successfully at ${LOCAL_JSON_FILE_PATH}`);

        // Verify the content of the file
        fs.readFile(LOCAL_JSON_FILE_PATH, 'utf8', (err, fileContent) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Failed to read updated file content:', err);
          } else {
            console.log('Updated file content:', fileContent);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to update local JSON file:', error);
  }
}


cron.schedule('*/5 * * * *', async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Running scheduled task...');
    const record = await stepOne();
    const url = record.field_13347_raw.url; // Extract the URL from the record
    await stepTwo(url);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during scheduled task:', error);
  }
}, {
  scheduled: true,
  timezone: "Europe/Madrid"
});



